# if first advanced custom field is empty, use other within <a>-tag

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, advanced-custom-fields

So I am using Advanced Custom Fields for Wordpress, and I have a repeater sub_field where you either can link a file for download, or choose a page link in a different field for an  tag my page.
My two fields are named:
fil_url
page_url

This is my normal markup, which returns one, in this case the uploaded file.
php/html:

```
<a href="<?php the_sub_field('fil_url')):) ?>open</a>
```

So what I want is an if-statement that says that if fil_url is empty, then display page_url instead. But I'm not sure how to write this.
Plz help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $file_url = get_sub_field( 'fil_url' );
    $href = ( ! empty( $file_url ) ) ? get_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) : get_sub_field( 'page_url' );
    echo '<a href="' . $href . '">open</a>';
?>
```

Comment: It looks good, however I can't get it to work. seems to be some kind of error in `$href = ( ! empty( get_the_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) ) ) ? get_the_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) : get_the_sub_field( 'page_url' );`

Comment: I'm not familiar with ACF, but a quick Google search indicates you probably need to use `get_sub_field` instead of `get_the_sub_field`

Comment: does `(! empty( get_sub_field( 'fil_url' )))`check if 'fil_url' is empty or if the `href=""` is empty?

Comment: It checks if the subfield is empty.

Comment: As far as I can tell there's nothing wrong with the syntax. What's the error? Did you check the parent repeater field? e.g. `if(get_field('repeater')){while(has_sub_field('repeater')){`

Comment: I tried this:  `$href = ( get_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) ) ) ? get_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) : get_sub_field( 'page_url' );` and wierd enough it worked!

Comment: @diggy your code is wrong `empty()` will return error `Can't use method return value in write context`. You should do something like this `$file_url = get_sub_field( 'fil_url' );
$href = ( ! empty( $file_url ) ) ? get_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) : get_sub_field( 'page_url' );`

Comment: tnx Rahil, I assumed ACF worked similar to get_post_meta but obviously it doesn't :) feel free to post it as a new answer

Comment: As mentioned it did also work by just removing the `( !empty`-statement at the beginnin! (and the closing bracket obviously)

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering with @diggy's post I found this sollution:

```
<?php
$href = ( get_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) ) ? get_sub_field( 'fil_url' ) : get_sub_field( 'page_url' );
<?>
```